# Why Checksums are computed for the three layers

Tags: networking, checksum, tcp

I have been looking for an answer regarding this issue, I know why the need to have the checksum computed at both layer 3 and 4. Layer 4 computes the checksum considering the TCP Header, Data and Pusedo header. Layer 3's checksum only is concenered about IP header, however layer 2's checksum (FCS) considers the Layer 2's header and Data (which is TCP Header, IP header and the application data). Can't we only compute the checksum for the layer 2 header only.

Answer (score 0):

Corruption may occur during processing within the same layer or during passing the data as payload to the underlying layer. For the underlying layer, the received data would seem perfectly valid, since it has no information about how actually valid (layer+1) data looks like. So, every layer needs its own checksum.

Comment: Thanks addy2012, but my point is about the scope of the checksum computation, in Layer 4 all the fields are inputs to the checksum algorithm, in layer 3 only the IP header, in layer 2 again all the fields are inputs to the checksum algorithm.